# Linking executable statically to OpenSSL

Tags: c, gcc, openssl

I compiled OpenSSL and now I want to compile one of the examples from [here](http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls-samples.html) and use the OpenSSL that I compiled.

When I link the libraries dynamically, everything works fine:

```
gcc dtls_udp_chargen.c -o example -ldl -lcrypto -lssl -lpthread
```

but when I try to compile the example with the OpenSSL version that I compiled by myself I get following output:

```
gcc dtls_udp_chargen.c openssl/libssl.a openssl/libcrypto.a -o example -ldl -lpthread
/tmp/cc3SIZpa.o: In function `THREAD_setup':
dtls_udp_chargen.c:(.text+0x102): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
/tmp/cc3SIZpa.o: In function `THREAD_cleanup':
dtls_udp_chargen.c:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `CRYPTO_set_id_callback'
/tmp/cc3SIZpa.o: In function `connection_handle':
dtls_udp_chargen.c:(.text+0x146d): undefined reference to `ERR_remove_state'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas what is the issue here ? Everything is run on linux of course.

Comment: You have `-lcrypto -lssl` backwards.  libssl depends on libcrypto.  Instead use: `gcc dtls_udp_chargen.c -o example -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -ldl` I also move -ldl towards end, as OpenSSL also uses this.  https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gcc+linker+dependency+order&ie=utf-8